# Laravel 419 | Page Expire error in all Forms Submit

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

'Here is my .env File.'

```
APP_NAME=FSN
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:H6Yh5B/H2fB4GGWSHKWtsxzOclJzrdIb/frXiOuyYR0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://fieldservicesnationwide.com/
ASSET_URL=https://fieldservicesnationwide.com/public
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=thedatec_fsns
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=fieldservicesnationwide.com
MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

I Submit my Forms, but i face 419 error,in my local It works Fine but when i upload it into my Online Server, this errro Occurs!`

Comment: You might be missing @csrf token in the form

Comment: i think you are missed csrf token and add body  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> and add inside form tag   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

Comment: Your session might not be working. Check the write permissions of your `storage` folder and subfolders or use a session driver that is not `file`. Also make sure your domain matches what you use to access the site e.g. if you use the IP to access the site the cookies won't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't use `@csrf` in Blade template.